# È più corretto "vabbè" o "vabbé"?

Tags: accents, orthography

Posto che se non erro la grafia corretta sarebbe *va be'*, in caso per qualche motivo lo si debba scrivere in questa forma gergale, l'accento andrebbe grave (*vabbè*) o acuto (*vabbé*)?

Comment: Captain Schettino has his own way to say 'vabbè'. As it is shown on [this page](http://www.cadoinpiedi.it/2012/02/11/concordia_il_video_choc_vanno_sulle_lance_da_soli_schettino_e_vabbuo.html), while the ship was sinking he said '**vabbuò**'.

Comment: @KyriakosKyritsis it's a common variation, I'm not sure about its origin, but I've both heard and used it some times

Comment: @Lohoris It's the same expression said in Naple's dialect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question is not simple to answer to. Indeed this term is the short form of "va bene" (that's ok), and is rarely used in written texts.

But if you really want to write it, I would choose among three different forms:

1. *vabbè* which is how you pronounce it
2. *vabbe'* which is the linguistical correct form, with the truncation of "ne"
3. *vabbeh* which correctly represents the pronountiation (aspirated 'h' sound)

The first one is reported by the [accademia della crusca here](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_9/interventi/3982.shtml) and [here](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=1143&r=41032) and by [Dizionario di ortografia e grammatica](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=1143&r=41032)

Comment: Both links point to the same address, I guess you mis-pasted the first one.

Comment: _(riguardo alla lingua, ti indirizzo [a questo post](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian))_

Comment: I added another link (the original one I referred to. I left the additional one put by @Lohoris.

Comment: What do you mean by “mute h” in this context?

Comment: h is called also "mute consonant" because it is not pronounced. You could contribute to the site making a question like that.

Comment: IIRC “vabbe’” is a case of truncation, not elision (elision would be the loss of a single vowel, though still marked with an apostrophe)

Comment: right, I modify it

Comment: @Daniele B: I know what is meant by a mute consonant. I was wondering what it is that you mean. If “it is not pronounced”, how can it “correctly represent” something's pronunciation? We might as well write “hvahbbheh”, mightn't we?  :-)

Comment: @DaG you're right, I was not explaining enough and probalby mixing up two different concepts. In this case indeed the h is NOT MUTE but it is intended to represent the 'aspirate sound' of h. I'll hence remove the reference to mute h in my answer. Thanks for the comment, it helped improving the answer!

Answer (score 2):

As [pointed out by Daniele B.](/a/40), the correct spelling is *vabbè* -- which is the correct usage if you want to infer a (southern) dialectal inflection.

That said, if you want to simply use a gergal, yet dialect-transparent form, there exist three correct spellings:

> - *va beh*
> - *va be'*
> - *va be*

All are mentioned in this [Accademia della Crusca thread](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_9/interventi/3982.shtml).

Often seen, but incorrect, is the misspelled version

> - va bhe

Answer (score 2):

The online Treccani dictionary does not list an entry for this expression. It does list an [entry for the word `be'`](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/be/) (which is an abbreviation of bene which according to this dictionary has apparently made it into standard Italian, and I have quoted the online reference below):

> **Be’**
>
> **be’** *‹bè›* (o **beh**) interiez. – Troncamento fam. di *bene*, usato, con il senso di «bene, ebbene», in frasi interrogative o di
>   concessione: *be’, che succede?; beh! ... fate voi.*

Nevertheless, I wouldn't write "va be'", which is two words, because the b is pronounced as a double sound and since (1) in Italian double sounds only occur in the middle of words (they cannot occur at the beginning or at the end of a word like in other languages), and since, just as important, (2) the given word is part of nonstandard Italian, one can conclude that the best to write it as it is pronounced, ignoring everything else. Hence, IMHO, the most proper way to write this word is:

> vabbè

Regards.